# MySQL, Access Denied when executing query from command line

Tags: mysql

When i execute this command:

```
mysql -u c1user -pc1password c1database
```

I can successfully log in the database and execute queries, but if i try to run the query from command line like this:

```
mysql -u c1user -pc1password c1database < query.sql
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000) at line 1: Access denied for user 'c1user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

What could be the problem?

UPDATE: i tried using the root user instead of c1user and it worked.  The strange thing is that if i use c1user in MySQLWorkbench for example, i can execute the same query without issues.

Comment: Do you have a `use` statement at the beginning of your script which is switching to a database without access? Only logical scenario.

Comment: Are you able to `source query.sql` after login (with first command)? As @DanFromGermany pointed out, you need `use` statement otherwise it will most likely fail. Also you can see `at line 1` which means that user was actually logged in and file was about to be processed ...

Comment: @DanFromGermany i don't have a `use` command at the beginning of the script, just a select, it's really weird.

Comment: @rkosegi i tried doing a `source query.sql` (first i added a `use c1database` in the script file) and i still get the error: 

`mysql> source query.sql;
Database changed
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'c1db'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

Comment: you have saved the sql file from a schema (Database) which is not in the DB where you want to import. So 2 ways: 1) create the same database and import or edit the SQL file and remove the line USE xxxxx at the first lines

Comment: User `c1db` is not the same as `c1user `